# Pulling powers to the outside of expressions (inverting PowerExpand)

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

Is there something like an inverse of `PowerExpand` that pulls powers to the outside of expressions:

$$ x^2 y^2 \leadsto (x y)^2 \\
   x^2/y^2 \leadsto (x/y)^2 $$

I am happy to assume that $x$ and $y$ are positive reals,
but I do not see any of the algebraic commands that would do this even with the right assumption.

Comment: For formatting purposes, there are probably good ways to go about this. As for actually getting the expression to evaluate to such a construct, no, it's not readily attainable (there may be some hackish methods with `Hold`).

Comment: It would help if you could state the *reason* why you want this "inverse" in the first place. Is it supposed to happen only when the symbols `x` and `y` appear, or for any product? Is it only for formatting, or are you just trying to eliminate a variable?

Comment: @Jens I would like a general operation, ie `x` and `y` are pattern variables. The aim is to massage expresions prior to applying things like `Integrate`, `Reduce`,`Solve`, `DSolve`, `Limit` etc when these are not making any progress on the original expression. In particular this is motivated by http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58839/giving-hints-to-integrate, but it seems a generally useful operation to be able to perform

Comment: Do you have an example where it actually makes a **difference** in the functions you cite (`Integrate` etc.), if you *manually* replace a product of squares by a square of products (just to test what the effect would be)?

Comment: @Jens In the linked question it helps me work on the problem even if it does not seem to help Mathematica. Currently I just hand edited the expression to the form I want, but even if I end up doing things by hand, it would be nice to be able to express the steps as programmatic operations rather than hand editing each step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the goal of the question correctly, this is a possible application for the new [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) and [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html). Looking in particular at the documentation for [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html), under "Applications," you'll find many situations that look similar to the one in this question.

For example, you can enter a valid expression in the form

```
Inactivate[(x y)^2]
```

[image: inact0]

```
Inactivate[(x/y)^2]
```

[image: inactive]

The default transformation to canonical form is not performed until you call  `Activate` on it at a later stage. One could do similar things with [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) instead of `Inactivate`, and [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) instead of `Activate`.

Assuming this `Inactive` approach is an acceptable way of wrapping the desired form of your expression, you could define a rule that transforms patterns as follows:

```
combinePowers[expr_] := 
 Inactivate[expr, Power] //. 
  HoldPattern[
     Inactive[Power][z1_, n_] Inactive[Power][z2_, m_]] /; (Abs[m] == 
      n) :> Inactive[Power][(z1 Power[z2, Sign[m]]), n]
```

Here I only inactivate `Power` and then replace products of terms with head `Inactive[Power]` into a single power, provided the exponents are either equal or of opposite sign. The `//.` is there to make it work for more than two factors, as well:

```
(1 + x)^2 y^2  z^2 // combinePowers
```

[image: 3 term output]

For fraction, the output of `Inactive` is a bit clumsy-looking,

```
(1+x)^-2 y^2  z^2//combinePowers
```

[image: fraction]

but nevertheless it's valid once you do this:

```
Activate[%]
```

[image: fraction active]

Comment: I need to look at this tomorrow, but the examples certainly look right. Thanks!